# shoppe gem: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#buy

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubygems

I'm trying to use the shoppe gem in rails for e-commerce. I followed exactly the same thing as instructed by the guidelines in http://tryshoppe.com/docs . I did manage to set up the application, create admin and create product, but the problem was at the "Basket"(http://tryshoppe.com/docs/tutorials/baskets) section, when I tried to 'add to basket' in the view page, it throws an error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#buy
Couldn't find Shoppe::Product

the error highlighted the line :

```
@product = Shoppe::Product.find_by_permalink!(params[:permalink])
```

which returned nil.

Just for a check, I even copy pasted the whole code just to make sure it was not about typo.

I really need help here as I tried figured out numerous times on what went wrong .

Comment: have you run all the generators that it asked you to do. Ex: `rake db:migrate shoppe:setup` ? . and you should have a module called `Shoppe` inside your models folder. One more test you could do is to run `Shoppe::Product` in `rails console` and see if it works..

Answer (score 1):

If you add `root` to the find product line in the **Buy** action it should fix this. The whole line should read…

```
@product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink!(params[:permalink])
```

The line in the **Show** method in the same controller gave me the solution to this problem.